# Extract c# object from json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json and I want to get it in my c# object.

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

Here, I get the Json in the format of:

```
{{
"pipeline" : {
"url" : "url1",
"idP" : 1
},
"id": 1234,
"name" : "test1",
"state" : "inprogress",
"date" : "date"
}}
```

Now, from this JSON, I just want the id and idP.

How can I do that? Should I create a class with all the properties?

Can I please get a sample code?

Comment: *"Should I create a class with all the properties ?"* - Yes.  Or at least just the properties you want.  `object` has no meaningful or useful properties, so you should define the type that you want to use.  Alternatively you could use something like `dynamic` and dynamically read the properties, if they are present at runtime.

Comment: Plug your JSON into [this website](https://json2csharp.com/), and use the resulting C# classes to deserialize the JSON.  Note: I removed the starting and ending braces to get it to work.

Comment: So, I plug in and get many c# classes. But, I want to use only 1 class and some of its properties, then can it be still used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want  id and idP, you don't need to create the classes and deserialize json. You can just parse it

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);
    var id = (Int32)jsonParsed["id"]; //1234
    var idP = (Int32) jsonParsed["pipeline"]["idP"]; //1
```

but you have to fix your json, by removing extra pair {}. You can make it manually if it is a typo. But if it is a bug, you can use this code, before parsing

```
json=json.Substring(1,json.Length-2);
```

or for example you can create one class

```
 public class Pipeline
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int idP { get; set; }
    }
```

and deserialize only one part of json

```
Pipeline pipeline = jsonParsed["pipeline"].ToObject<Pipeline>();
```

Comment: I was thinking to add a class, but my json contains many classes where as I just need one class. Can I just use 1 class and deserialize to that 1 class ?

Comment: @hellotemp10 Yes you can deserialize just  one property . See my updated answer.

Comment: Just a quick question, should I be using `[JsonProperty("id")]` ? In my c# class ?

Comment: @hellotemp10 [JsonProperty("id")] you can use if you want your c# property start from upper case - Id  but json is lowercase for example.  But Newtonsoft.Json usually don't need it.